# MYSQL Order BY "entry" DESC Not showing the highest

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having a slight problem with this mysql query.

```
          $sql = "SELECT name FROM videos ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5";
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
      $list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo $list['counter'];
          echo "<br>";
      }
      mysql_free_result($result);
```

Want i'm wanting to achieve is it listing 5 entrys by order "Counter" But when listing it? it only shows 4 entrys like so :-

```
5648
4575
1595
35
```

So where is my 5th entry? and why isn't it posting it? NOTE that the 5th entry is also the highest with a value of

```
305355
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, i had a similar problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *fetch* before the loop which pops one record off the result set (i.e. `305355`).

```
$list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // REMOVE THIS LINE
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // output code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the code and use `mysqli_` functions

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM videos ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $list['counter']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this code..

```
      $sql = "SELECT name FROM videos ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5";
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

      while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo $list['counter'];
          echo "<br>";
      }
      mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling mysql_fetch_assoc two time that is why your first row get by first time you called the mysql_fetch_assoc and remaining show in second calls